# Body height 100% не работает

Tags: html, css

Почему html,body и .wrapper принимают высоту 150px? Хотя контента в них на 1500 px

```
html,
body,
.wrapper, {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Оставь `html` и `body`  в покое, это к чему  `min-height: 100%; height: auto !important;` ?

Перепиши вот так:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Запятая ломает правило. После класса `wrapper`.

```
 html,
    body,
    .wrapper {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
    }
```

Comment: без запятой то же самое....

Comment: тогда добавляйте воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```